# Retrieve data from database (SQL Azure) and display in webpage without using Entitiy Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As stated in the question, how to retrieve data from database (using SQL azure) and display in **MVC webpage** without using Entity Framework? Any other solution?

Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Regards,
William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "raw" ADO .NET and work with good old data sets, data readers etc. See this link, for example: [How to: Connect to SQL Azure Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336243.aspx).

Comment: I managed to connect my SQL Azure to my MVC project. However, I have a part where I need to display my datas from database to webpage (in table form). I have problem display all the details. :(

Comment: @WilliamTioWeeLeong, could you be more concrete? What problem you have exactly?

Comment: I am currently doing some sort like a shopping cart website using ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Role. I am currently stuck in a part whereby i have to do a search from list of product which display on the table. Therefore a filter method is required to filter the data. However i stuck in the implementation of the function as i am using entity framework to list all the datas from SQL Azure. Is there any other way to approach this problem? Or issit possible to implementation the data presentation by using another method rather than EF in MVC Project?

I hope you could understand my problem.... :(